# Stuck on Boilerpipe

Tags: javascript, html, url, jar, boilerpipe

Fairly excited about this utility, but running into some issues with implementation. Installed it but getting no result with execution of HTML file on server. Syntax error on the URL code.

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


 URL url = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.com");
 var text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);

document.write(text);

</script>
```

EDIT =====> This code appears to have worked.

```
<?php 


$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

?>


<script language="JavaScript" src="boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var sStr = "<?php echo $html?>";

  var text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(sStr);

document.write(text);
```

?>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boilerpipe is a **Java** library, not a **JavaScript** library. The relationship between the two languages is only slightly deeper then the relationship between a **Car** and a **Carpet**.

If you want to use Boilerpipe within a webpage then you'll need to either write a Java Applet that exposes the API to JavaScript, or write a web service that exposes it over HTTP (and then access it using Ajax).

Comment: Ah I see. I had hoped to use the Article.Extractor function on PHP string variables ...

Comment: Made some kind of progress. Although it doesn't appear to be calling that function.

Comment: Well, first … the generated string is not going to be a valid JS string, and second … you **still** can't directly hit a Java API from a JavaScript program!